# Max height container with very tall fixed position container inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having some trouble with a very basic CSS problem.

I have a container that has a max-height of 655px. Now to the very right of that container is a fixed position container (it must be fixed position due to what I'm doing). The fixed position container has an absurdly large height.

It needs that height because it will be filled with content, that you'll ultimately see by clicking buttons and by some javascript. (changing the scrollTop)

I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong, but I basically need only 655px of the fixed position container to show. I'm not really sure why this doesn't work the way I have it setup.

Check out the JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BG2bu/

```
.tall {
background-color:blue;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
width:200px;
height:5000px;
}
```

I'm using this CSS to define the tall container. And I know if I change the position to absolute, it will constrain to the max height of it's parent container. I really need this container to be fixed though for other reasons. Is there any possible way to do this? Am I missing something simple here?

If this can be done with a JS/Jquery solution I'm definitely open to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this would be suitable for your needs but I've wrapped the `.tall` div with another container as `position:fixed` will not adhere to `overflow:hidden` in its container div.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DZ53/

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if this suits your need or not, but could you...

```
.tall {
    max-height: 655px;
    overflow: scroll / hidden;
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't work for me unfortunately.

The .tall container is filled with lots of absolutely positioned elements which seem to shift when I change the max height.

Comment: Tough to advise further without a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Can you share a link?

Comment: This is a little messy but: http://jsfiddle.net/nPXMj/

Basically I have a horizontal container, and a tall vertical container nested within it.

When you reach a specific point, the horizontal scrollbar controls the scrolling of the vertical container. Essentially I am doing this by changing the top and left position of the container...

This leads to very janky results when the tall container is filled with content.
Trying to edit that code to make it so the vertical container goes FIXED once you pass 1438 pixels...The problem is when its fixed, it no longer listens to the parents height.